# How do I achieve this kind of light star effect?

Tags: rendering, shaders, light, lighting, compositing-nodes

I'm kinda new to Blender. Currently playing around with version 2.8 to practice some rendering. Is there a way to achieve this 'light-star' effect for the blooming objects with the emission? If there is an alternative way then it's fine too. See these images below for references. Thanks in advance:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It can be done by running your bloomed image through a glare node in the compositor.

Comment: Also to help in your search it's called "Lens Flare"

Comment: Alright, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can connect it like this. Play around with the settings - "ghosts" looks good as well. The emission strength of the object being bloomed plays a factor also. See below:

[image: Glare]

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed.