# how to make an bright spot similar to a star?

Tags: modeling, rendering, texturing, materials, geometry

how to make an bright spot similar to a star ?  i  we tried to make a sphere and add emission to it
but it didn't work it only made the sphere clear bright without looking like a star
[image]

you know something similar to this image right here

Comment: Search for Lens Flare like here https://codeofart.com/flares-wizard/ you can try ten of them. In general all these lens artefact are done in post proces. Simple one can be done in Compositor with Glare node. Can be done also as set of images rigged in 3D or Eevee use simple Bloom effect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I achieve this kind of light star effect?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183638/how-do-i-achieve-this-kind-of-light-star-effect)

Comment: thanks guys for the help flares wizard achieved what i wanted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simple static lens flare you can try blender Composite nodes:

- Light source very small Object with high Emission like 1000.
- Big star is *Glare node* > **Simple Star**
  (Streaks works too, but I could not get them enough long)
- Central effect is based on *Glare node* > **Ghost Fog** "scratched" by **Cloud** Texture plus **Sun Beams** node.

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

For advanced  and more flexibility try this https://codeofart.com/flares-wizard/

Comment: thanks dude for your answer, but sadly because i don't use blender 2.8 that much i couldn't use these nodes to link them to my object :( because i don't know how,but flares wizard did achieve what i want thanks again :)

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos What is the common strategy of closed Q. Should I move this answer to your link to make the answer useful? Thanks